# SSIS Package Configuration File

Tags: sql, ssis

Hello we have some SSIS packages with XML file configurations. Basically we configure the database connection, password, etc. to run the packages in different environment (Production vs. Testing). We use a 3rd party software to run our SSIS packages on target SQL servers. The packages run fine on our Testing environment, however fail miserably on Production server. The difference is SQL server on testing is vs. 2016, while on Production only 2012.

There are various error messages on why they fail on production, some of them about "Failed to load at least one of the configuration entries for the package..". And then there are some that cannot login to the database connection provided in the XML files, even though the info is 100% correct.

Does anyone know if XML config file is not supported in SQL 2012?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be going from a test environment that's a different version than your production environment, it will only lead to more headache in the future.
If you can't upgrade production then I'd suggest getting another test system on the same version as production.

That being said...

The functionality is there in 2012, but the format probably isn't the same.

You need to set the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2012 in Visual Studio under Project > Properties and build the project again.

[Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp3lJ.png)